langchain RetrievalQA error: ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'query'}
In a RAG project, I am using langchain. When I run the QA chain with query input, this error keep showing up:
----> result = qa_chain({'query': question})
ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'query'}

Here is my code:
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

# Build prompt
template = """Given the following context answer the question.
    Context:
    {context}
    ------------------
    Question: {query}
    Answer:"""

# LLM chain
QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm,
    retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
    return_source_documents=True,
    chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT}
)

question = "What methodology was used in this research paper?"

result = qa_chain({'query': question})

# Check the result of the query
result["result"]
# Check the source document from where we 
result["source_documents"][0]


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

RetrievalQA has been deprecated. Try this instead:
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

system_prompt = (
               "Use the given context to answer the question. "
               "Context: {context}"
           )
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", system_prompt),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)

question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, QA_CHAIN_PROMPT)
chain = create_retrieval_chain(vectordb.as_retriever(), question_answer_chain)
   
result = chain.invoke({"input": question}) 

